# Rails error while working through JumpStartLabs Blogger 2 Tutorial(trying to implement tag deletion)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been fighting with this error for a while now and I'm sure that it is something simple that I am missing. I'm working through the Blogger 2 tutorial by jumpstartlabs(http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i3:-tagging).

I'm attempting to implement a way to delete existing tags through the UI. I'm stuck trying to resolve this error:

No route matches [POST] "/tags/3"

My routes.rb is:

```
Blogger::Application.routes.draw do
 root to: 'articles#index'
 resources :articles do
    resources :comments
end
  resources :tags
end
```

and here is my tags controller:

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
def show
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
end
def index
    @tags = Tag.all
end
def destroy
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
    @tag.destroy

    flash.notice = "Tag '#{@tag.name}' Deleted!"

    redirect_to action: 'index'
end
end
```

Finally, here is the page that I'm displaying the deletion link on:

```
<h1>All Tags</h1>

<ul id="tags">
    <% @tags.each do |tag| %>
        <li>
            <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag), class: 'tag_title' %>
            <%= link_to "Delete", tag_path(tag), method: :destroy, data: {confirm: "Really delete the tag?"} %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to "<< Back to Articles List", articles_path %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm still getting the same error after restart.

Comment: What's the output if you run `rake routes` in your terminal? A delete route should be `[DELETE] "/tags/3"` in Rails 4, as `POST` is used for   `create` actions.

Comment: What version of Ruby on Rails are you using? (find by running `rails -v` in your terminal)

Comment: I'm running rails 4.1.4 and rake routes shows:
DELETE /tags/:id(.:format)

Comment: What happens if you change your `<%= link_to "Delete", tag_path(tag), method: :destroy, data: {confirm: "Really delete the tag?"} %>` line slightly. change `tag_path(tag)` to just `tag` and see what happens.

Comment: Just tried that and it is still throwing the same error.

Comment: Strange, it looks alright to me. Try posting the HTML that is rendered by your webpage. Maybe that will help.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is that JavaScript is disabled, which would cause problems with this Rails helper. Check out this link: http://railscasts.com/episodes/77-destroy-without-javascript-revised

Comment: I believe it's `method: :delete` instead of `method: :destroy`

Comment: The relevant HTML looks OK to me, but I am a newcomer to this:
    
<a rel="nofollow" href="/tags/1" data-method="destroy" data-confirm="Really delete the tag?">

Also, JavaScript is definitely running!

Comment: Also, using method: :delete throws the same error.

Comment: Make sure you have //= require jquery //= require jquery_ujs into application.js and change method: :destroy to method: :delete

Comment: @Saqib I double checked for both of the //=require lines and they are present. Both :destroy and :delete result in the same error.

Comment: The issue is definitely that the action is sending a POST route, not a DELETE route. I just don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BillTurner mentioned, try changing method from `:destroy` to `:delete`.  Make sure you save the change, reboot the server, and let me know if that works.

Comment: OK, here's what worked:

Changing method in my view to :delete, keeping my defined method in the controller named "destroy" and having it call @tag.delete.

Without the "destroy" method being defined in the controller it doesn't work, I'm wondering why? Nowhere in my code do I actually call the destroy method, I only ever call delete.

Anyways, thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

that answer didn't work out for me, but I found elsewhere that `=>` fixed it

```
<%= link_to "delete", article_path(@article), :method => :delete, data: {confirm: "Really delete the article?"} %>
```

(that's in the view `app\views\articles\show.html.erb`)